# UITapGesture on UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

When there are no images on UIImageView, this code always crash.

Set the tap.

```
if imageView.gestureRecognizers == nil || imageView.gestureRecognizers!.count == 0 {
    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "fullImage:")
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}
```

And then, use the photo browser.

```
func fullImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    let attachedView = sender.view!!.superview!
    let images = attachedView.subviews.map{ ($0 as! UIImageView).image! }
    let imageView = (sender as! UIGestureRecognizer).view! as! UIImageView
    let tag = imageView.tag

    let photos = IDMPhoto.photosWithImages(images)
    let browser = IDMPhotoBrowser(photos: photos, animatedFromView: (sender as! UIGestureRecognizer).view!)
    browser.displayToolbar = false
    browser.displayActionButton = false
    browser.displayArrowButton = false
    browser.displayCounterLabel = true
    browser.scaleImage = imageView.image
    browser.usePopAnimation = true
    browser.setInitialPageIndex(UInt(tag - 1))
    ...
```

Is there any good way to avoid nil crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let images = attachedView.subviews.map{ ($0 as? UIImageView).image }.filter { $0 != nil }
```

That way your code won't crash if a subviews turns out to be something else than a `UIImageView` and you can filter out the ones that returned nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the code in `if let` :

```
if let image = imageView.image {
   let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "fullImage:")
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem that I will crash the following code.

let images = attachedView.subviews.map{ ($0 as! UIImageView).image! }

Comment: try to use the following `attachedView.subviews.map { ($0 as! UIImageView).image }.filter { $0 != nil}`

Comment: @pixyzehn, are you changing something with image ? the code i wrote checks if the image is found then you can call the method fullimage so that shouldn't happened !